# Nginx 301 redirect of a single URL

Tags: linux, nginx, rewrite

I am trying to redirect a specific URL like:

http://www.domain.com/cadena-de-metas

I am doing this via my config file in /sites-available/

```
    if ( $request_filename ~ cadena-de-metas/ ) {
            rewrite ^ https://some-other-url.com? permanent;
    }
```

This works, but sadly it redirects as well this URL:

http://www.domain.com/uploads/descarga-cadena-de-metas.jpg

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using if statements, they're not great for performance. Try something like this : ~* means case insensitive regular expression match, and regular expressions can just be literals. If it doesn't work let me know, it will just need a small tweak - not sure if you need the speech marks

```
server {
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location ~* "^/cadena-de-metas" {
    return 301 https://some-other-url.com;
  }
}
```

Your return could alternately be this if you want it to adjust to http / https automatically

```
return 301 $scheme://some-other-url.com;
```

If you wanted to redirect to another location on the same server, it would be something like this

```
return 301 $scheme://$host/subdirectory;
```

**NB**: Do all testing with 302 redirects, as they're not cached, and change to 301 redirects when you're happy with how things are set up.

You do generic redirects from the non-www to the www of a domain differently, but you haven't asked so I won't post that.

As well as a redirect you can do a proxy_pass, that will fetch content from another location and show it on that URL.

Comment: Do I need to cater for www and non-www versions?

Comment: I have tried it but it doesnt work, does these need to go in the server block?

Comment: My original answer and comment above weren't quite right. I've edited the answer, which I've tested on my own nginx install, which should be right now.

Comment: I'm sorry but I get the same problem. It redirects other URLs that contain the same name as well. So for example an image file that lies in several directories but have the same name. Any ideas?

Comment: Good point, I missed a character sorry. You need the ^ character before the slash, which in regular expressions means "at the start of the string". This means it will only match when it's at the root of the server, not a path. I've tested that and it seems to work. Sorry for the oversight.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still doesnt work :( I have these two URLs: 
http://www.habitualmente.com/suscribete/
http://www.habitualmente.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/suscribete1.jpg

You will see that they both redirect 301 to the same URL. The second one should show the image.

Comment: Please post your nginx config. The second one does show the image for me though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33930/discussion-between-tom-and-snowball).

Comment: Do your testing with 302 redirects, as 301's are cached. You need to clear your browser cache and restart the browser It's working fine for me.